# Mapping a strange datestring as an NSDate in Restkit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, nsdateformatter

I have a `JSON` that contains a start and end date. But their look like this in the `JSON`

```
EndDate: "/Date(1375693200000+0200)/"
StartDate: "/Date(1375686000000+0200)/"
```

I know that you can add `NSDateFormatters` to your `RKEntityMapping` but I don't know how I can do this? This is how I normally do it

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        //dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

        [RKEntityMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

but the strings inside json are no dates. seems more like a time interval. try to extract the values 1375693200000 and create the date with time interval

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1375693200000;
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

Answer (score 0):

The date you are receiving is an ASP.NET JSON date. RestKit has date for matter specifically for this: [`RKDotNetDateFormatter`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDotNetDateFormatter.html). Learn how to use it [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#transforming-date-and-time-representations).